# geom_label_repel() above geom_line()

Tags: r, ggplot2

So I have this ggplot where labels are positioned by the geom_label_repel() method. It's fairly okay, but I woud like the labels to be, all of them, above the geom_line(), not below, which is what happens in some cases.

[image]

This is the code that produces the graph:

```
    ggplot(data,
   aes(x=daydelta,y=day1ret)
   ) + 
  geom_line(color='steelblue',size=2) +
  geom_label_repel(aes(label = paste0(round(day1ret*100,2),"%")),box.padding = unit(0.6, "lines"),label.size = 0.1)+
  scale_x_continuous(limits = c(1,15),breaks=1:15,minor_breaks = 1:15) +
  scale_y_continuous(limits = c(0,1),breaks=seq(0,1,0.1),minor_breaks = seq(0,1,0.1),labels = paste0(seq(0,1,0.1)*100,"%")) +
  ggtitle("RETENTION BY USERID") +
  theme(plot.title = element_text(hjust = 0.5))+
  xlab("Days from Register\n (baseline: Day 1)")+
  ylab("Retention as % of returning users from Day 1")+
  geom_segment(mapping=aes(x=daydelta,y=0,xend=daydelta,yend=day1ret),size=0.5,color="red",linetype=2)
```

Comment: have a look at `nudge_x` and `nudge_y` for `geom_label_repel`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Instead of cluttering up the plot with labels offset from the data line, why not place the labels at their actual x and y values? This is visually much cleaner and won't distract or mislead viewers by placing labels in locations other than the data values they represent. For example:

```
library(ggplot2)
library(scales)

dat = data.frame(x=1:10, y=c(1, seq(.3,.1,length=9)))

ggplot(dat, aes(x,y)) +
  geom_line() +
  geom_label(aes(label=paste0(sprintf("%1.1f",y*100),"%")), size=3, label.padding=unit(2,"pt")) +
  scale_y_continuous(labels=percent, limits=c(0,1)) +
  scale_x_continuous(breaks=dat$x) +
  theme_classic()
```

[image]